# How to create this type of cycle?

Tags: time-series, finance, cycle

I'm currently working with an enormous timeseries dataset in a CSV file. There is around 73 000 of observations and I need to slice them for backtest.
I tried going via while and for loops, but they didn't work out at all and cycle simply ran into infinity even with break rule. Itertools also didn't help much.

If I try to describe what I'm trying to get - 
Assume there is 10 observations (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10).
And I need to create a cycle slice of (1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5) and so on till (9,10). 
But without manual coding it like this

```
slice(1,2,1)
slice(2,3,1)
slice(3,4,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ii is very not clear what you want. If taking 2 elements or 3 elements in `R` you can do this with `combn` function:

```
t(combn(1:10, 2))

t(combn(1:10, 3))


# > t(combn(1:10, 2))
# [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    2
# [2,]    1    3
# [3,]    1    4
# > t(combn(1:10, 3))
# [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    2    3
# [2,]    1    2    4
# [3,]    1    2    5
# [4,]    1    2    6
```

If it is a big data set you will probably have memory issues.
The number of possible combinations is ....

```
> choose(73000, 3)
[1] 6.48335e+13
```